# Showing 0 element in the list while web scraping using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.espn.in/nba/stats/player?stat=assists&season=2017&seasontype=2&position=center&conference=5"
page=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
elem=soup.find_all("table",class_="flex")
len(elem)
```

After executing this code it's showing me zero elements in the list. Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: Try `page.text`

Comment: I have tried even not working.

Comment: I visited that site and checked html i assume that you are querying wrong element. The table you want is in `div` tag

Comment: There is no table with `flex` class. Go to the site and in console try this `document.querySelectorAll('table.flex')`. Shouldn't work

Comment: can you try it using my code and let me know is it working or not?

Comment: I tried all the class name and its still showing me the same result as 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no table element with `flex` as its class. In the page there are two tables, left aligned and right aligned tables. The left table contains the names and right aligned tables contain all the table corresponding to the names.

You can get the left table using:

```
soup.find("table",class_="Table--fixed-left")
```

And the right table using:

```
soup.find("table",class_="Table Table--align-right")
```

Comment: Brother! how can i find the exact table class?

Comment: You can use the [dom explorer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/dom) in your chrome browser to find the class on the table

Comment: brother i'm using Dom explorer but unable to find exact class.....Can you do a favour...just find out full table class in https://knoema.com/atlas/topics/Tourism/Travel-and-Tourism-Total-Contribution-to-GDP/Contribution-of-travel-and-tourism-to-GDP

Comment: You can find the tables using `soup.find("table",class_="table.fht-table")`

Comment: but its not working...can you try my code again and just import that table in pandas frame work. website link for table  https://knoema.com/atlas/topics/Tourism/Travel-and-Tourism-Total-Contribution-to-GDP/Contribution-of-travel-and-tourism-to-GDP

Comment: I think the reason its not working is because the table is not server side rendered, so beautiful soup can't find the tables. You should try something else like selenium or any headless browser

Answer (score 0):

I have blocking software that blocks me from browsing this site, and I can't check on live.
But it is worth checking that this class is on the page itself and not on a frame (or etc) in itself.